# In Excel I have two columns, I want to highlight based on text values in the right col

Tags: excel, formatting

Is it possible to do this with conditional formatting?

Say if the right clumn has the word "TRUE", I want to highlight the cell on the left of the column green.

this is what i tried:

cell value if true =$I:$I,$L:$L,$O:$O but it not applying to the column to the left, just the column with the text match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Excel I have two columns, I want to highlight based on text values in the right column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809886/in-excel-i-have-two-columns-i-want-to-highlight-based-on-text-values-in-the-rig)

Comment: can you help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to select the range you want the formatting to apply (green in your case), then look for the white cell, in my case, it's A2 the white cell, and use a formula that will work for this particular cell, in my case, it would be when B2 is TRUE, so I use `=B2=TRUE`:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Why does this not work when selecting the entire column?

Comment: @Dave It works when selecting the entire column. You need to make sure the formula you are using applies for the whiter cell in the selection you have. Also, what do you mean exactly by 'this does not work'? Is there no highlighting at all? Or something else?

Comment: oh ok, I was using L2 instead of L1, it is working now . thanks

Comment: @Dave Ok, good to know :) Thanks for letting me know it's woking!